# CardLayout not showing next card

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am having troubles with showing the next card with the card layout, I read the docs and various threads here. Code is "working", but as stated, does not show the next card. The three cards work separately, but not are not visible when accessed through the next() method

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Start().createFrame();
}

public void createFrame() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Card().createMainGui();
        }
    });
}

class Card1 extends Card {

    public Card1() {
        createGui();
    }

    private void createGui() {
        /*
         * Create buttons and add them to the Card1 Panel
         */

        final JButton button = new JButton("Next");
        button.addActionListener(this);

        add(button);
    }
}

class Card2 extends Card {

    public Card2() {
        createGui();
    }

    private void createGui() {
        /*
         * Create label and add it to the Card2 Panel
         */

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Card2");
        add(label);
    }
}

class Card extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame;
    final JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout(20, 20));

    void createMainGui() {
        /*
         * create main frame
         */
        frame = new JFrame("Testframe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /*
         * add the different cards to the Card Panel (Card Layout)
         */

        Card1 card1 = new Card1();
        cards.add(card1, "card1");

        Card2 card2 = new Card2();
        cards.add(card2, "card2");

        // Card3 card3 = new Card3();
        // cards.add(card3, "card3");

        /*
         * add the Card panel to the frame, pack it and make it visible
         */
        frame.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
        cl.next(cards);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve]. An MCVE would have imports, only one **public** class (other classes pasted in after it are fine), one `main(String[])` method to run it all once it compiles cleanly without any changes.

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do, you mix your components, and it remains confused what are these objects (`cards, Card2, Card3`) ?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have added the start class with the main method too. All three classes are public, but one after another. is that OK?

Comment: @BoHalim the cards is the main cardlayout, while card1, card2 and card3 are the cards to be added to the cardlayout

Comment: You only want to overlay `JPanels`  and move from one to the other?

Comment: yes, correct. And I wanted to use CardLayout for that. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: *"is that OK?"* Is it possible to do a single copy/paste, class definition, compile & run to see the problem?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have fixed this now into one class for easy compiling & run

Comment: My apologies for the delay. The drive on which I store projects is failing, so I can't start the IDE. I just realised that a simpler program can edit/compile/run Java source, so am using it instead. One of the first problems is that `Card` extends `JPanel` and defines a `final JPanel cards ..`. This means that each of `Card1` and `Card2` each define a `cards` panel and neither of those can show the other card, Start to fix the problem by not having `Card1` or `Card2` extend `Card` and turn the `Card` class into a method in the `Start` class. Declare a single instance of `cards` ..

Comment: .. as an attribute of the `Start` class, so it can be accessed as and when needed by any card. Then add each card (a plain `JPanel`) to that single instance. Give it a try and if you are still stuck, [edit] to update the MCVE, and me know.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewThompson
A mate of mine told me just what you told me in the above and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault in my code was, that I extended the `Card1` and `Card2` classes from the `Card` class. Thus, they inherited also the method of creating the variable `cards`. In the `EventListener`, the wrong `cards` variable is referenced (the one created in class `Card1`) and therefore, the `EventListener` does not work.
Solution: remove the `extend` in `Card1` and `Card2` and move the `EventListener` into an inner class of the class `Cards`

```
private class NewBlaBlaListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

and add it the `ActionListener` within `Cards` to the `Card1`

`card1.addNewBlaBlaListener(new NewBlaBlaListener());`

Cheers

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. :)